# Mongoose Multiple Databases TypeError: users.model is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to use Mongoose's example for defining models in a separate document from their schemas (whilst having multiple databases).

Mongoose's Docs example for User.js:

```
const userSchema = require('./userSchema');

module.exports = conn => {
  conn.model('User', userSchema);
};
```

However, I am getting errors

> (TypeError: users.model is not a function)

that I suspect come from the database promise that `mongoose.createConnection(...).`. 
The structure is as followed

```
-models  
  -user.js
-schemas  
  -userSchema.js
-app.js
```

I have cut information that I don't think is apart of the problem (noted ...) but let me know if I need to include anything else. 
App.js:

```
...
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var logger = require('morgan');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var generatorRouter = require('./routes/generator');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// connect databases
var users = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/users', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
.then(function() {
  console.log('usersDB connected')
}).catch(err => console.log(err))

var userData = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/userData', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
.then(() => console.log('userDataDB connected'))
.catch(err => console.log(err))


app.set('trust proxy', 1)
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  secret: shhhhh,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

//set up passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
var User = require('./models/user')(users);

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/g', generatorRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
    console.log(User);
    User.findOne({
        username: username
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        if (!user) return done(null, false);
        if (!user.authenticate(password)) return done(null, false);
        return done(null, user);
     });
   })
);

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
...
module.exports = app;
```

user.js

```
var userSchema = require('../schemas/userSchema');

module.exports = users => {
  users.model('User', userSchema);
};
```

userSchema.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  "email": {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  "username": {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  "password": {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  "date": {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
})

//generate hash
userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8));
};

// password checker
userSchema.methods.authenticate = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};

module.exports = userSchema;
```

I've also tried using User(users) and User(await users) but neither works for trying to pass the database into the User function.

Answer (score 2):

your user.js is incorrect. You cannot use users.model('User', userSchema);
it should be like this

```
var userSchema = require('../schemas/userSchema');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = () => {
  mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
};
```

Comment: This is if I want to have one connection. I am trying to have one model associate with one database. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in user.js file, the model function comes from mongoose so you need to create instance of mongoose and use it to create the model by .model()
so the rewrite of the code will be something like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSchema = require('../schemas/userSchema');
module.exports = users => {
  mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
};
```

i hope it works